# Laravel GET route error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a very simple web app created in Laravel 5.5:

There is a database with a list of coupon codes that have either not been redeemed or been redeemed. 0 is not redeemed and 1 is redeemed.

When someone enters a string into a HTML form input and submits it, Laravel goes to a route with that string as a variable.

The Controller code is as follows:

```
public function redeemCoupon ($coupon_code)

    {
        $coupon = Coupon::where('coupon_code', $coupon_code)->first();

        if ($coupon === null) {
            return view ('pages.no-coupon');
        }

        else if ($coupon->redeemed == 1) {
            return view ('pages.used-coupon');  
        }
        else {

            $coupon->redeemed = 1;
            $coupon->update();
            return view('pages.redeemed-coupon', compact('coupon') );
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

You can try it out here:
http://178.62.4.225

Everything works fine when done normally, tested on the code "code01". When I enter it and it hasn't been redeemed, it says so, and redeeming it changes the column in the database from 0 to 1. If I try the process again it tells me it has already been redeemed.

The issue is when I'm on the page that tells me it's been redeemed:
http://178.62.4.225/redeem-coupon/code01

If I refresh it with CTRL + R, it just reloads and says it's already been redeemed. But if I paste the URL into a new tab or click into it and refresh by clicking enter, it gives " MethodNotAllowedHttpException" and the resulting debug screen, from what I can tell, offers nothing of use.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
Route::post('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

to

```
Route::any('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

Did the trick

Comment: Why any and not get method?

Comment: GET gives the same error I was using as POST. I also need it to do both; if "redeemed" in the DB = 0 I need POST to change it to 1, if it already = 1 I need it to return the view that says so with GET.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a GET request and define a post route change

```
Route::post('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

to:

```
Route::get('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

Comment: This still gives the same error. But I don't see how that would work as it needs to be a post request for when the code hasn't been redeemed, in order to change the DB column from a 0 to a 1?

Comment: @RuairiMcNicholas So you should load the page and then check the coupon status with post request via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Is redeemed set as protected? Also displaying app_debug true displays all your DB connection info (user and pass)

More than likely to be due to the _method.

What page is _method = "POST" on?

Comment: In the Coupon model I have it listed under "protected $fillable = [" which I think means its protected, should it not be?

Comment: @RuairiMcNicholas Thats just for when the model is updated. It is probably to do with the _method assigned to it. Each _method associates to a route type. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing